# Postfix install does not display setup windows

Tags: postfix, fail2ban, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install Postfix on an Ubuntu 16.04 server; this is a web server. I need Postfix for send-only for fail2ban and logwatch.

All Postfix tutorials show that apt install postfix ends with dialog windows. When I run sudo apt install mailutils all I get is a completed script, no install (that I can tell).

How do I configure my install? (there is no /etc/postfix/main.cnf)

Sorry for the lack of support info. I do not know enough to know what to give you. Ask, and I will post what I can.

Comment: Are you looking for `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix`?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I am not sure. Will that take me through the remain installation steps?

Comment: For your kind of purposes you don't need normally a fully blown MTA; you can also use nullmailer or ssmtp instead of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending more time than I should have, I removed and reinstalled Postfix. This action resolved the problem. I guess I had a bad initial install.

My steps:

1. sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove postfix
2. sudo apt-get install mailutils

I hope this helps someone else.